# C# Custom text file based resource provider that allows space in keys

Tags: c#, text, resources, provider

I have read much about .resx files and know that we can also create a custom resource provider which may support db or XML.

I have a requirement however where my keys will contain spaces. Plus I want them in a simple .txt file. No .resx or XML files.

An example would be like:

```
My Key 1=Hello Dude
My Key 2=Hello world
```

I was wondering if there is any way to fetch such keys in .net by writing some custom resource provider in C#. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Would [JSON format](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W1rFSs) do?

```
var someText = "{\"my key 1\" : \"hello dude\", \"my key 2\" : \"hello world\"}";

JObject resource = JObject.Parse(someText);

foreach (var p in resource.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine("The key is {0} and it's value is {1}", p.Name, p.Value);
}
```

Dependency: `JSON.Net`

Hth...

Comment: Don't need json. Just a simple text file with key=value format

Comment: @FaisalMushtaq Yes, that's what JSON _format_ is, keys and values, and can be saved in a `txt` "file" (or `.json`, or whatever extension). If that's too much then you can save a text file exactly like how you typed it and just parse it. One key/value pair per line, delimited by an `=` or whatever delimiter you choose..and gets us to simple CSV or TSV etc _formatted_ files.